# which object do i bind this jquery toggle event to

Tags: jquery, toggle

I'm using jquery `toggle()` to change some css like this and it works great...

```
$("#button").toggle(
    function(){
        $("#playlist").css("bottom","0");
    },
    function(){
        $("#playlist").css("bottom","-200px");
    }
);
```

I want to trigger this same thing when the letter m is pressed, so i added it to a case (it is set up where i can make a case for the key pressed):

```
.... 
case 77: // M
   What object to I bind to the toggle function?
```

What Object do I use there to do the same function as above?

**Thank you everyone for your really helpful answers!**

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To invoke an event handler manually, first you must define your functions as named functions instead of anonymous functions:

```
$("#button").toggle(on, off);

function on(){
    $("#playlist").css("bottom","0");
    isOn = true;
}
function off(){
    $("#playlist").css("bottom","-200px");
    isOn = false;
}
```

Next, you can then invoke the handlers manually and use a boolean as a switch:

```
case 77:
    if(isOn == true) {
        off();
    } else {
        on();
    }
```

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - After reading the docs, I realized I made a few incorrect assumptions. My original response was going to be to used named handlers. I've edited this to eliminate the inaccuracy.

Comment: This is a good idea, i see your sharing the functions which is what I was also trying to do

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution is to trigger the `click` event on the `#button` element:

```
case 77: // M
    $("#button").trigger("click");
```

Since [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) binds to the `click` event under the hood, this will call the appropriate handler.

Comment: Thanks could work for my first example, but how would it be done using `toggle`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment, but you cannot use the "show or hide element" form of `toggle()` to trigger the handlers bound by the "handle alternate clicks" form of `toggle()`. Both forms have very different purposes.

Comment: What if clicking the button does more than toggle the playlist? Unintended consequences.

Comment: @Mike, it cannot. As documented [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/), this form of `toggle()` unbinds all the registered `click` handlers before installing its own, and calls `preventDefault()` from its handler.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi both comments have very helpful explanations. I'm starting to see I'm using this function incorrectly.

Comment: @Frédéric, I do not think that is the case. Additional click() handlers bound with toggle() will not be prevented (only default behaviors are prevented). Example: http://jsfiddle.net/nzR7q/1/

Comment: @Mike, interesting, this seems to go against the documentation (unless I misunderstood it). Let me check the source code.

Comment: The docs say that you unbind toggle by unbinding click. It doesn't say that toggle unbinds or prevents other bound clicks.

Comment: `.preventDefault()` after the function is what it says to prevent default click action

Comment: @Mike, looks like you're right, I was interpreting `we must unbind click to remove a behavior attached with .toggle(), so other click handlers can be caught in the crossfire` the wrong way. So it's true than triggering `click` can have unrequested side effects if other handlers are bound to that event.

Answer (score 1):

`toggle` event method is [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/), you can use `css`'s function and  `which` property of the `event` object:

```
$("#button").on('click', function(){
    $("#playlist").css("bottom", function(i, bottom){
        return bottom === '0px' ? '-200px' : '0px' 
    });
});

$(document).on('keyup', function(event){
   if (event.which === '77') {
      $("#playlist").css("bottom", function(i, bottom){
          return bottom === '0px' ? '-200px' : '0px' 
      });
   }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NPKKR/

Answer (score 1):

you can save the state like this:

```
case 77: // M
     var button = $("#button");
     if (button.data("toggled") == true)
     {
           $("#playlist").css("bottom","0");
           button.data("toggled","true")
     }
     else 
          {
           $("#playlist").css("bottom","-200px");
           button.data("toggled","false");
         }
```

maybe this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The key thing to understand is that `toggle()` is a mouse event... just a special case of click. So you can't use it to implement a keyboard event.

I'd probably just write a function to represent the work, then bind it or call it in the relevant event handlers (click, keydown)

```
var f = function() { 
    var state = $('#playlist').css('bottom');
    $('#playlist').css('bottom', state=='0px' ? '-200px' : '0px');    
}
$('#button').click(f);
​​​​​​​$(document).keydown(f);​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var pos=0;

    // On Key press
    $(document).keypress(function(e){
        if(e.which == 109 || e.which == 77) {
        if(pos==0){
        $('#playlist').css('bottom','0px');
        pos = 1;
        }else{
        $('#playlist').css('bottom','200px');
        pos = 0;    
        }
    }});

    // On Click
    $('#playlist').click(function(){
        if(pos==0){
        $('#playlist').css('bottom','0px');
        pos = 1;    
        }else{
        $('#playlist').css('bottom','200px');
        pos = 0;    
        }
    });
});
```